# while filtering the data from dataframe TypeError: must be real number, not str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

we have a dataframe as

```
print(df)

Empld   EmpName  Date
1234    Ram      2020-01-01 01:01:01
2332    Andy     2010-11-11 01:01:01
2233    Jim      2009-01-11 01:01:01
```

when i try to filter the data in the dataframe

```
dfemp = df[df['Empld'] == '1234']

print(dfemp)

Empld   EmpName  Date
1234    Ram      2020-01-01 01:01:01
```

my code is like below i am trying to assign only date value to a variable as the dataframe will always have only one record with id '1234'

```
if dfemp.empty :
    EmDt = "2000-01-01"   
else :
    EmDt = dfemp['Date'].values[0].replace("[","").replace("]","")[:10]   

i am getting below error 

Error: TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Is there any way to overcome this error, i am trying to get final output to a variable

```
EmDt=2020-01-01(if it has value then "2020-01-01" if not "2000-01-01" static value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that all columns in *df* are of *string* type.

When you create *dfemp*, it is a *DataFrame*, and you want to read
*Date* column from the first row, also as a *string*.

To do it run:

```
if dfemp.empty:
    EmDt = "2000-01-01"   
else:
    EmDt = dfemp.iloc[0].Date[:10]
```

*replace* is not needed here.

Another detail to check:

```
print(type(dfemp.iloc[0].Date).__name__)
```

The result should be "str". If the result is other then there is
something wrong / unexpected with your source data.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I understood from your question, this should work.

```
dfemp['Date']= pd.to_datetime(dfemp['Date'])

if dfemp.empty :
    EmDt = "2000-01-01"   
else :
    EmDt = dfemp['Date'].dt.date[0]
print(EmDt)
```